Unrecognized extension value in extension set ([object Object]) when working with vue-mirror
currently using codeminior in vue3
"codemirror": "^6.0.1",
"vue-codemirror": "^6.1.1"
                            <div class="flex-col ">

                                <div class="w-[620px] h-[550px] overflow-y-auto">
                                        <codemirror
                                        ref="mymirror"
                                        :autofocus="true"
                                        :placeholder="$t('commons.noData')"
                                        :indent-with-tab="true"
                                        :tabSize="4"
                                        style="height: calc(550px)"
                                        :lineWrapping="true"
                                        :matchBrackets="true"
                                        theme="cobalt"
                                        :styleActiveLine="true"
                                        :extensions="extensions"
                                        v-model="selectedData"
                                        :disabled="disabled"
                                    />
                                </div>   
                            </div>   

<script setup lang="ts">

import { Codemirror } from 'vue-codemirror';
import { javascript } from '@codemirror/lang-javascript';
const mymirror = ref();
const extensions = [javascript(), ]; //oneDark
const selectedData = ref('');
const disabled = ref(false);

</script>

The code seems to be all right, but running the code outputs an error saying:
chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16802 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unrecognized extension value in extension set ([object Object]). This sometimes happens because multiple instances of @codemirror/state are loaded, breaking instanceof checks.
    at inner (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16802:15)
    at inner (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16782:9)
    at inner (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16782:9)
    at inner (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16782:9)
    at flatten2 (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16806:3)
    at _Configuration.resolve (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:16719:21)
    at _EditorState.create (chunk-P4Q3QBM3.js?v=13caf26d:17366:40)
    at j (vue-codemirror.js?t=1719172443687&v=13caf26d:2998:22)
    at vue-codemirror.js?t=1719172443687&v=13caf26d:3047:15


Could you make a reproducible example? Would be super helpful. In the meantime, try downgrading the @codemirror/state package if you have that installed

It is used to work in a couple days ago without changing any code, but now it just failed without a reason. could be related to some package upgraded, let me try
